# Ftp send only files that are new with python

Tags: python-2.7, ftplib

I'm using this code to upload all htm files to a web server but every time I run it I upload all files and I would like to upload only the new files.

```
try:
ftp.cwd('public_html')
F=open('Simple.png','rb')
tp.storbinary('STOR Simple.png',F,1024)
file.close(F)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\Relatorio'):
    for fname in files :
    if (fname.endswith(".HTM")) or (fname.endswith(".htm")):
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + fname, open(fname, 'rb'))
            print "FTP Enviado"
            except ftplib.all_errors,e:
            print 'Erro ao conectar ao servidor FTP\nErro:',e
```

Comment: have you thought about using a version control system like svn or git? it would be a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use the "last modified" time of the local and remote files as a crude way of estimating whether or not a file has changed since it was last uploaded.

Comment: There is a program in Ruby that performs a similar function for web hosts that don't support rsync or some other synchronization mechanism: https://github.com/aizatto/git-deploy - this is the same ideas as last modified but leans heavily on local version control to get the job done efficiently.